# How do I set Quill output to be JSON/delta instead of html?

Tags: quill, react-quill

What do I need to do to set Quill's content or output to be JSON/delta instead of HTML?

I can't believe I'm asking such a simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

There's nothing about how to set the format in either the [QuillJS doc](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) or [react-quill doc](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#using-deltas).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactQuill, from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

export const Comment = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  function submit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(value) # This currently returns HTML instead of JSON
  }

  return (
    <>
        <ReactQuill theme="snow" value={value} onChange={setValue}/>
        <p>{value}</p>
        <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(yourData)

Comment: @Shah - No, that's still just returning HTML.

Comment: Your setValue only returns an empty string. So your value state never changes to anything other than an empty string.

Comment: onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}

Comment: Also what do you mean by it’s returning HTML? What’s the type of your data?

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help but are you familiar with QuillJS or React's state hook? I'm following the instructions for the react-quill component (https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#quick-start) but the input (ie "value" in my OP) is literally HTML rather than the Delta format (https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/). So it's returning ```<p><strong>Gandalf</strong> the <em>Grey</em></p>``` instead of ```{ ops: [ { insert: 'Gandalf', attributes: { bold: true } }, { insert: ' the ' }, { insert: 'Grey', attributes: { italic: true } } ] }```

Comment: What if you try console.log(new Delta(value));

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the [`onChange` prop](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#props) is a function that has the HTML contents as the first argument, which will be the value used by `setState`. You'll want to define a custom function that sets `value` to [`editor.getContents()`](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#the-unprivileged-editor), which returns a Delta representing the current document.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactQuill, from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

export const Comment = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  function submit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(value);
  }

  // onChange expects a function with these 4 arguments
  function handleChange(content, delta, source, editor) {
      setValue(editor.getContents());
  }

  return (
    <>
        <ReactQuill theme="snow" value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <p>{value}</p>
        <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As above denoted answer by **person_v1.32**.The handleChange method receives four params second param is the delta you can simply use that to get delta.
You can send it to the database or in your react state whatever suits you.

```
 // onChange expects a function with these 4 arguments
  function handleChange(content, delta, source, editor) {
      setValue(delta);
  }
```